# Jquery: My class does not function during second call

Tags: jquery, class

I am new to jQuery.just learn and use it for 3 weeks until now.
I have written a class to organize stuff.
I call my method with more than 2 events,but the event does not work during my trigger of the second event.
there's nothing wrong with the selector.
I think there's something missing in my class. I don't know.
please help!
here's the snippet:

```
$("#btnPersonalNext, #btnDocListBack, #pDocList").livequery('click',function()
{
  var docListContent = 'loadDocumentList.php';
  $("#contentpaper").addContent(
  {
    _tag:'div',
    _id: 'contentDocList',
    _class: 'content',
    _content: docListContent,
    _heading: 'Document List'
  });
  //store personal info in session:
});
```

`addContent()` is the function.
when I click `#btnPersonalNext`,this works, but for `#btnDocListBack`, not any-more.

here's  my class (`jquery.content.js`). what it does is load html into a certain `_tag` with a particular `_id`.

```
(function($)
{
  $.fn.addContent = function(options)
  {
    var defaults = {
      _tag: 'div',
      _id: '',
      _class: '',
      _content: '',
      _heading: '',
      _clearExisting:'yes',
      _insertAfterID:'',
      _deleteBeforeInsert:'no'
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function()
    {
      obj = $(this);
      if(options._clearExisting=='yes'){
        obj.empty();
      }
      if(options._deleteBeforeInsert =='yes'){
        $('#'+options._id).remove();
      }

      var innerHtml = '<' + options._tag + ' id="' + options._id + '" class="' + options._class + '">';
      if(options._heading!=''){
        innerHtml += '<h2>' + options._heading + '</h2>';
      }

      if(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.php(\??([A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)(&[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?$/.test(options._content))
      {//if .php
        $.get(options._content,function(data)
        {
          //handle response from server here.
          innerHtml += data;
          innerHtml +='</' + options._tag + '>';
          if(options._insertAfterID !=''){
            $('#'+options._insertAfterID).after(innerHtml);
          }
          else{
            obj.html(innerHtml); 
          }
        });
      } // PHP rule 
      else
      {// .html
        innerHtml += options._content;
        innerHtml +='</' + options._tag + '>';
        if(options._insertAfterID !=''){
          $('#'+options._insertAfterID).after(innerHtml);
        }
        else{
          obj.html(innerHtml); 
        }
      } // HTML rule 
    }); // End of Returned Function
  };// End of addContent definition
})(jQuery);
```

hoping for answers, thank you so much!

here's my DOM structure:

```
<!-- JS  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/jquery-1.2.6.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/jquery.livequery.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery_plugins/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/jquery.session.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/jquery-plugin-wrapinner.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/jquery.content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_plugins/osra_main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">   
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headercontent">Please Enable JavaScript to Continue</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebarpaper" class="left">
            <!-- sidebar contents (class="sidebar")-->
        </div>
        <div id="contentpaper" class="right">
            <!-- main contents (class="content")-->
        </div>
        <div id="modals" class="clear">
            <!--modal pop-up window -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><p></p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am loading the content dynamically in div with id `#contentpaper`.
I don't know how to rebind, other that using livequery plugin, with this usage:
`$("#btnID").livequery('click',function(){});`

-bgreen1989

Comment: I cannot see where the buttons you are talking about are defined ? btnDocListBack  btnPersonalNext etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a quick look over and the code size was a little hard to diagnose, so I re factored a  bit hoping to make it more understandable to myself and others.

What I think is PART of the problem and a BADTHING(TM) is your generation of html by gluing strings together. This can break DOM event binding, and render really awful code.

Also, seeing you are relying on live-query, the "glue strings together" method may not be triggering the dom events required to make live-query trick (Not Certain) and you /may/ find using DOM methods to generate  DOM elements should solve this problem

```
(function($){
  $.fn.addContent = function(options)
  {
    var defaults = {
      _tag: 'div',
      _id: '',
      _class: '',
      _content: '',
      _heading: '',
      _clearExisting:'yes',
      _insertAfterID:'',
      _deleteBeforeInsert:'no'
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var phpregex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.php(\??([A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)(&[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?$/;

    var x_generateElement = function()
    {
      var container = document.createElement(options._tag); 
      $(container).attr("id", options._id); 
      $(container).addClass(options._class);
      if(options._heading!=''){
        var header = document.createElement("h2"); 
        $(header).text( options._heading ); 
        $(container).append(header);
      }
      return container;
    };

    var x_preClear   = function( obj )
    {
      if(options._clearExisting=='yes'){
        obj.empty();
      }
      if(options._deleteBeforeInsert =='yes'){
        $('#'+options._id).remove();
      }
      return obj
    };

    var x_addElement = function( e , obj )
    {      
      if(options._insertAfterID !=''){
            $('#'+options._insertAfterID).after(e);
      }
      else{
        obj.html(e); 
      }
      return obj;
    };

    return this.each(function()
    {
      var obj = x_preClear( $(this) );
      var container = x_generateElement(); 

      if( phpregex.test(options._content)){
        $.get(options._content,function(data){
          //handle response from server here.
          $(container).append(data);
          obj = x_addElement(container, obj);
        });
      } else {
        $(container).append(options._content);
        obj = x_addElement(container, obj);
      } 
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```